# Set value in the object with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, object

First, here is my code:

```
var lastUsedId = '';
var object = {
    element: lastElement()
};

function lastElement() {
    return lastUsedId;
}

lastUsedId = 123;

console.log(object); // returns `{element: ""}` and should `{element: 123}`
```

As you can see, I have defined object with key `element` which should contain last used element's ID. Problem is that I don't know that ID yet it comes to print the result. I can't change the value like `object.element = 123` because of my robust application, so don't send comments like that. For this question, it has to bee structured like that.

My question is: can I set the value like function, which returns the variable with content changed afterward? Maybe it is stupid question, but when it is not possible just say it and I will try to find other way.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to check for an updated value. Something that executes `lastElement` and creates a new `object` with the updated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, but you can use a `getter` for that:

```js
var lastUsedId = '';
var object = {
    get element() {
      return lastElement()
    }
};

function lastElement() {
    return lastUsedId;
}

lastUsedId = 123;
console.log(object);

lastUsedId = 456;
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> can I set the value like function, which returns the variable with
>   content changed afterward?

Why not keep the value as a `function` only

```
var obj = {
    element: lastElement
};
console.log( obj.element() ); //this will invoke the method to get the latest value
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to recommend also but @gurvinder372 beat me to it.

Comment: I send this `object` variable to the external plugin which expects string, so it uses like `obj.element` without call.

Comment: @debute in that case you should go with Dekel's answer

Comment: Yea I see it, he did what I needed. Thanks anyway.